# Can't get cookies of a domain from requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

```
import requests

r2 = requests.get('https://google.com')
print(r2.cookies['1P_JAR'])
```

When i try that, it outputs `2022-12-30-18`

But when i try replacing the domain name with `https://roblox.com`
and the cookie to `.ROBLOSECURITY`

Which looks like this:

```
import requests

r2 = requests.get('https://roblox.com')
print(r2.cookies['.ROBLOSECURITY'])import requests
```

Returns a error saying

```
  File "c:\Users\user\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(r2.cookies['.ROBLOSECURITY'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 334, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 413, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError(f"name={name!r}, domain={domain!r}, path={path!r}")       
KeyError: "name='.ROBLOSECURITY', domain=None, path=None"
```

I'm trying to get the cookie named .ROBLOSECURITY from the domain https://roblox.com using the requests module in python.

Comment: Why am i still getting no answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Session with requests, then you should be getting cookies.

When I access the website you mention, then I don't have the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie but try this code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://roblox.com')
print(response.cookies.get_dict())
```

Comment: Yeah, the cookie is only avaible when the user is logged in.

Comment: Do you get the cookie when you use Session?

Comment: that code that you sent only returns me {'GuestData': 'UserID=-1189373494', 'rbx-ip2': ''}

Comment: Does the code you send return all the cookies? Or only the .ROBLOSECURITY one

Comment: It returns all cookies

Comment: I think the problem is that the requests is getting a new cookie instead of getting the existing one the person has. That's why it returns guest cookie, guest cookie is available when the user is not logged in and the .ROBLOSECURITY is available when they are logged in, do you have any other python modules that could help me with that?

Comment: Does the cookie have `httponly` and `secure` set?

Comment: I dont know, im not sure on whats ```httponly``` and ```secure``` im new to using the requests module in python

Comment: see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the dictionary to a string? When i run the thing it sends all the cookies as a dictionary.

Comment: Just realized that you actually answered your own question. Because you said that the cookie only exists if authenticated. The request is not authenticated. Figure out what authentication they use and add the auth param to the get method with the authentication type and then you get the cookie.